# Can anyone help me with a dropdown tab that looks like this :D

Tags: html, css, wordpress

[image]

Can anyone help me with the css, to get this look, i have the html for the dropdown etc. I just need the css for the customization :D

Comment: Add some code so we can see your structure

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Just inspect the element you're interested in. All websites are inspectable.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the person who asked the question tried nothing of his own. Looks like a homework post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've re-purposed some code from an old project to give you a start on the functionality you're after

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).click(function() {
    $('.wrapper-dropdown').toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.wrapper-dropdown {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 12px 15px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #c6bba2;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  color: #c6bba2;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.wrapper-dropdown:after {
  content: "+";
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  color: #c6bba2;
}

.wrapper-dropdown .dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #c6bba2;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  /* Hiding */
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper-dropdown .dropdown li {
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.wrapper-dropdown .dropdown li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #c6bba2;
  padding: 10px 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c6bba2;
}

.wrapper-dropdown .dropdown li:last-of-type a {
  border: none;
}

.wrapper-dropdown .dropdown li i {
  margin-right: 5px;
  color: inherit;
  vertical-align: middle;
}


.wrapper-dropdown .dropdown li:hover a {
  color: #57a9d9;
}

.wrapper-dropdown.active {
  background: #c6bba2;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  color: white;
}

.wrapper-dropdown.active:after {
  border-color: #c6bba2 transparent;
}

.wrapper-dropdown.active .dropdown {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c6bba2;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown" tabindex="1">Size & Fit
  <ul class="dropdown">
    <li><a href="#">Size 8</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Size 10</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Size 12</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The more options you add the more you will have to tweak the max height of `.wrapper-dropdown.active .dropdown`

Hope this helps!